# Enable/Disable a control when a certain gridview row is clicked ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a clickable gridview row made through javascript wherein every time I click a certain item in the gridview, the whole row is selected and highlighted.

So here's my javascript for that..

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var RowID = $('#<%=RowKey.ClientID%>').val();
            if (RowID != "0") {
                $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id=' + RowID + ']').css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "black" });
            }

            $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').click(function() {
                $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "Black" });
                $(this).css({ "background-color": "Black", "color": "White" });
               $('#<%=RowKey.ClientID%>').val($(this).attr("id"));
            });

            $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css({ cursor: "hand", cursor: "pointer" });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

How can I disable a certain button in a webform when a user clicks on the row?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button has an id of myButton, can't you just add a statement to your onClick handler like so:

```
$("#myButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Its not working
I tried to write it this way..
$("#btnEditUser").attr("disabled", true);
still no effect

Answer (score 0):

`$("#btnEditUser").attr("disabled", true);`
will not work because at run-time the id will change.
So you if you have only one button in the row you can go as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var RowID = $('#<%=RowKey.ClientID%>').val();
        if (RowID != "0") {
            $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id=' + RowID + ']').css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "black" });
        }

        $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').click(function() {
            $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "Black" });
            $(this).css({ "background-color": "Black", "color": "White" });
           $('#<%=RowKey.ClientID%>').val($(this).attr("id"));
           //this line will disable all the button of the row clicked
           $(this).find("input:button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });

        $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "hand", cursor: "pointer" });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Or you can put a css-calss on your button say (.btnEdit) and your function will like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var RowID = $('#<%=RowKey.ClientID%>').val();
    if (RowID != "0") {
        $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id=' + RowID + ']').css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "black" });
    }

    $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').click(function() {
        $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "Black" });
        $(this).css({ "background-color": "Black", "color": "White" });
       $('#<%=RowKey.ClientID%>').val($(this).attr("id"));
       //this line will disable all the button of the row clicked
       $(this).find(".btnEdit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    $('#<%=UserGrid.ClientID%> tr[id]').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css({ cursor: "hand", cursor: "pointer" });
    });

});
```